# Best way to terminate a thread from inside the thread or any other safe way

Tags: c, multithreading, c++11, networking, posix

Background:
So I am writing a network based application. The application has a part where the threads loops indefinitely and performs some action, also there are other threads which come to life when a new request is received (P.S. these are pre spawned threads).

So, now the question is: These threads mostly use static data, I have not yet come across a situation where I need to dynamically allocate some resource.
So these threads use static data, and when the user wants to close the program or the program receives a termination signal, I want to terminate the threads in a safe manner.

**So what would be the best way to terminate threads internally or any other safe way**

I know declaring global vars would be bad, even if they're atomic or stuff.

Thank you.

P.S: I'm fine with POSIX or C++11 thread based solutions anything is helpful.

Comment: If your threads never have side-effects, why are you running them at all? If they *do* have side-effects, how could terminating them possibly be safe, unless their side-effect is completely atomic and cannot be interrupted to cause the program's invariants to be broken?

Comment: I get what you're saying @EOF , edited the question accordingly, and I see my threads do have some side effects, and it would not be safe to terminate them from outside. Thank you.

Comment: I'd say that depends. What are your threads doing? Waiting for I/O (in that case, they shouldn't be threads, instead the I/O should be done by I/O-multiplexing)? If they are mostly computing instead, how often do they have to interact with other threads to obtain input or pass on output? In the worst case, they are totally CPU-bound, and don't have natural waiting points where you could synchronously poll for a signal. In that case, you may have to use fully asynchronous signals, and *you* have to ensure the signaled thread terminates gracefully without doing damage.

Comment: In general, threads are a bad abstraction. Try to think of I/O multiplexing and tasks instead. Futures/promises can possibly help organize the program sanely, especially if they are asynchronously cancellable.

Comment: I can agree about the "it depends" part. But for my case, i guess threads are essential because there are multiple clients involved, and there's a master socket pushing newclientsockfd to the message queue (this uses IO Mux) which is then taken up by the prespawned threads to communicate which might take long time, and hence for multiple clients to connect, i guess threading would be the right option. Also about **using tasks instead**, i have not yet explored tasks. I'd go read about them now. Thanks for the suggestion. But anything related to the good practice for this particular situation?

Comment: Waiting for multiple separate I/O channels with threads is a *classic* misuse of threads. Instead, I/O-multiplexing can wait for multiple sockets at once. Have a look at libevent/libev/libuv/folly/libcurl etc. Every *sane* system uses I/O multiplexing, among other things because a purely threaded server implementation will be absolutely murdered by a slow loris attack.

Comment: that's what's happening, IO multiplexing for waiting and once a connection is received, new FD is passed onto one of the threads for further communication with the connected client, to do the same for multiple client the master socket which is basically using IO multiplexing pushes each new FD to the message queue for the free threads to take up and communicate further with client. Also the number of pre spawned threads are limited so is the maximum number of backlog connections

Comment: That's `accept()`, which is -by itself- **not I/O-multiplexing at all**. I/O-multiplexing would be something like `poll()`, where the listen-socket is registered, and new connection sockets are *also* registered with the pollset, so until the slow network *actually* provides data, the open connections don't consume relevant resources. Only when enough data has been received to handle the request is a thread from a thread-pool notified to handle the computational part of the transaction.

Comment: I get what you're saying, Thank you for your help @EOF

Comment: If at all possible, terminate the threads by calling your OS 'terminateProcess()' API, or wrapper thereof.  If that is not possible, try to redesign your app so that it is.  If you cannot, you will have to put up with the other awkward/difficult/impossible means to terminate your threads with user code:(

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a way to give some kind of work to a running thread (the FD), why don't you add a way to give it a "stop" command?

Comment: let me now introduce 2 pools of threads, one pool of threads perform work based on whatever they pick from message queue, and the other perform same task indefinitely irrespective of any other changes to the program. How do we tell the other pool of threads to terminate? Also just look at the conv. with @EOF

Comment: "indefinitely" should be replace with some kind of "untill", so instead of having a "while(true)"  you should have a mutable condition. If you don't want to use globals you can pass some kind of reference between the parent and child thread in the thread creation void * argument.

Comment: this would be possible for a safe exit, however if the program receives a terminate signal, we cannot alter the reference var, and hence would result in an abrupt termination

Comment: For some signals there is nothing you can do to make a "nice exit", however if you are referring to SIGTERM, it could be caught   and "interpreted" any way you like.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for the signals that can be caught, can you please suggest some ways to terminate threads that do not involve any global variables.

Comment: TerminateProcess().  It is the ONLY guaranteed way to terminate all app threads in a simple and prompt manner.  User code cannot guarantee that and, in many of those cases where user thread-termination can be written, it would have to be maintained, ie. retested against likely OS and environments:(